# Passing shared variable after login with Laravel 5.5

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-5.5

i created a method in order to share datas with all views of my application.

For this i created a class EntityRepository where i store the datas I want to share with all views.

**Those data are displayed in the layout NOT the view.**

```
class EntityRepository
{
    use App\Valuechain;

    public function getEntities()
    {
        $vcs = Valuechain::select('valuechains.id', 'lang_valuechain.vcname', 'lang_valuechain.vcshortname')
            ->join('lang_valuechain', 'valuechains.id', '=', 'lang_valuechain.valuechain_id')
            ->join('langs', 'lang_valuechain.lang_id', '=', 'langs.id')
            ->where('langs.isMainlanguage', '=', '1')
            ->whereNull('valuechains.deleted_at')
            ->get();
        return $vcs;
    }
}
```

When I want to send datas to the methods I simply call the getEntities() method... For example :

```
public function index(EntityRepository $vcs)
{
    $entitiesLists = $vcs->getEntities();

    // My code here ...
    return view('admin.pages.maps.sectors.index', compact('entitiesLists', 'myVars'));
}
```

In this specific case it works fine and i don't have issue. My issue concerns the landing page after login.

**In the loginController :**

I defined the redirectTo variable this way  :

```
public $redirectTo = '/admin/home';
```

For specific reasons I had to override the authentificated() method in the LoginController in order to check if my app is configured or need to be setup ...

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{

    $langCount = Lang::count();
    if ($langCount == 0) {
        return redirect()->to('admin/setup/lang');
    }
    else {
        //return redirect()->to('admin/home');
        return redirect()->action('BackOffice\StatsController@index');
    }
}
```

The concerned index() method is sending the variable onto the view :

```
public function index(EntityRepository $vcs)
{
    $entitiesLists = $vcs->getEntities();
    return view('admin.home', compact('entitiesLists'));
}
```

Whatever the return i make i have error message...

Undefined variable: entitiesLists (View: C:\wamp64\www\network-dev\resources\views\admin\partials\header-hor-menu.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue by changing my routes :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (){
        $checkAuth = Auth::guard('admin')->user();           
        if ($checkAuth) {
            return redirect('/admin/main');
        }
        else {
            return redirect('admin/login');
        }
    });
});
```

In my loginController i changed :

```
public $redirectTo = '/admin/home';
```

to :

```
public $redirectTo = '/admin/main';
```

Finally :

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{

    $langCount = Lang::count();

    if ($langCount == 0) {
        return redirect()->to('admin/setup/lang');
    }
    else {
        return redirect()->to('admin/main');
    }
}
```